# Why does DomainEvent not harm testability?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm reading some articles discussing [DomainEvent](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) pattern. But I have a question how to write tests with it.

For example:

```
public void commitTo(Spring aSpring) {
    ...
    DomainEventPublisher.intance().publish(new BacklogItemCommitted(.......))
}
```

How do I test it? It's difficult to mock DomainEventPublisher because it's an singleton. I find a solution in [Working effectively with legacy code](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Working_effectively_with_legacy_code.html?id=CQlRAAAAMAAJ):

```
public class DomainEventPublisher {
    private DomainEventPublisher singleton;

    public void setSingleton(DomainEventPublisher singleton) {
        this.singleton = singleton;
    }
}
```

Adding an injecting method for test double and disipline the team not to use it in production code. But this seems to be drawback to testbility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in Udi's article, you don't need to inject an implementation of an interface because tests can simply add required handlers to the publisher directly. In your test setup method, you add the appropriate handlers. As part of performing the test, you ensure the handlers ran as expected. Then in the test tear down, you clear the handlers.

Comment: + 1 Thank you. I know few about .net and totally confused with the test code snippet " p => P.Customer" or something like that. It looks like I need a Singleton to bootstrap an ApplicationContext for dependency injection in production code.

Answer (score 1):

all problems in IT can be solved by another layer of indirection:

```
public void commitTo(Spring aSpring) {
    getDomainEventPublisher().publish(new BacklogItemCommitted(.......))
}

protected DomainEventPublisher getDomainEventPublisher() {
    return DomainEventPublisher.intance();
}
```

now in your test simply override the `getDomainEventPublisher()` method with one that returns your mock `DomainEventPublisher`:

```
@Test
public foo() {
    // arrange
    DomainEventPublisher mockDomainEventPublisher = mock(DomainEventPublisher.class);
    MyObject testObject = new MyObject() { 
        @Override
        protected DomainEventPublisher getDomainEventPublisher() {
             return mockDomainEventPublisher;
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: +1, thank you, this is another feasible sulotion. Subclass then override in Working effectively with legacy code, but these kind of solutions usually hint the code is difficult to test and hence raise my question